# cleanup Google Streetview related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

This morning I was doing a bit of cleanup of [google](/questions/tagged/google) when I came across [streetview](/questions/tagged/streetview) and [street-view](/questions/tagged/street-view).

Both of these should be retagged to / synonyms for [google-street-view](/questions/tagged/google-street-view).